# c++builder FDConnection to SQLite after compile the exe

Tags: sqlite, c++builder

I created a Script with c++Builder 11 with Datas stored in a sqlite3 db File.
To Connect to the Sqlite3.db, i used the FireDAC-Connection inside c++builder and all works fine.

In the Connection-Manager (DataExplorer) of C++Builder i set the Path to "D:\TEST.db".
If i share the Compiled Exe to another PC, then its possible there is no Drive D.
I tried in Connection-Manager to use only the Filename "TEST.db" without Path, but ends in a FireDAC Error Message: "FireDAC..Stan..Definition .. not found in []"...

i also tried "@scriptdir & "\TEST.db" in the Connections-Manager.. but dont works, too...

how can i save my TEST.db (sql3-database) in the ScriptDir if the Connection is fix via "FDConnection1" ????

thanks for any help..
Greeting.

Comment: you need to pass the db location as an argument to you program

Comment: Did you read the documentation yet? [Using SQLite with FireDAC](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC)

Comment: @RemyLebeau link to RAD Studio documentation has DB issues ..  connection and workflow is correct, but seems to miss this section...could you please give a hint?

Comment: @pm100 in c++builder  i have to connect the db via the "DataExplorer" ...  u mean to set a variable with db-path and set FDConnection->Database=@scriptdir & "\Test.db"  FDConnection->enable=1 at start of program?...

Comment: @doomerino "*link to RAD Studio documentation has DB issues*" - yes, but (until Embarcadero fixes it) if you keep refreshing it then it will eventually load. "*could you please give a hint?*" - at runtime, before connecting to the DB, use the `TFDConnection.Params` property to set the `'Database'` parameter to the DB's file path.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your tip...  got it . great..     :o)   have a nice day all

Comment: @pm100 thank you, too for your answer.  thumpbsup

Answer (score 1):

You could use the BeforeConnect for pointing your FDConnection Object to the correct database file. In the example below it would point to a database file named "test.db3" which is located in your exe's folder:

```
void __fastcall TForm4::FDConnection1BeforeConnect(TObject *Sender)
{
    dynamic_cast< TFDConnection * >( Sender )->Params->Database =
        ExtractFileDir( Application->ExeName ) + "\\test.db3";
}

void __fastcall TForm4::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    FDConnection1->Connected = true;
}
```

best regards, Herwig